# access denied. PHP script

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form, when submitting on my [page](http://www.medical-device-regulations.com/contact) says 'Access denied.' There is nothing else, so I can't seem to figure out how to debug.

Here is the code :

```
<?php

    $EmailFrom = "username@email.com";
    $EmailTo = "username@email.com, username2@email.com";
    $Subject = "Subject";

    $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
    $Company = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Company'])); 
    $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
    $Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel']));

    $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

    // Validation
    $validationOK = true;
    if (! $validationOK)
    {
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
        exit;
    }

    // Prepare Email Body Text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $Name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Company: ";
    $Body .= $Company;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Tel: ";
    $Body .= $Tel;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Further comments: ";
    $Body .= $Message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // Send Email 
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");

    // Redirect To Success Page 
    if ($success)
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Thanks for your message, somebody will get in touch with your shortly.");</script>';
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../contact\">";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>alert("There has been an error, please try again later.");</script>';
        echo '<script>history.back(1);</script>';
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working, could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please don't link to live code. It ensures that your question is useless after you've fixed the live code so it no longer exhibits your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers of the page you're submitting the form to are actually returning a HTTP 403 Forbidden error.

I'd suggest checking the file permissions & ownership of the contactengine.php file are correct as a first step.